# Change action bar buttons depending on current layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like a logout button to appear on my app's action bar only on a certain layout, for example, web.xml.  When login.xml is the current view, I don't want the button there.  Is this possible?

I currently have the button fully functioning, by utilizing the normal main_activity_actions method, but I can't figure out how to change what ones show depending on current content view.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Fragment or Activity that uses the `web.xml` layout, you would need to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method. There you can inflate a `menu.xml` with the desired icon and properties for the button you would like in the action bar.

To receive click events from this button, you would need to override the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` then ensure that the clicked button was yours and do your logic.

[More details can be found here on the Google Dev page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)